# AOB scan wildcrad generaor

Tags: python, wildcard, cheat-engine

i have no question i already found the solution and didnt seem to find a script like this after small search so why not contribute

the thing is : i needed a script that can compare texts (bytes) like [89 79 18 48 83 C1] and [89 79 18 48 13 C1] and [89 79 56 48 83 75] for CE AOB scan function when u try to make a script

i tried this code after some AI help and lot of promots since i couldn't trust AI chat to manually do this function cuz they did mess up

```
def compare_and_print(text1, text2):
    result = []
    for i in range(min(len(text1), len(text2))):
        if text1[i] == text2[i]:
            result.append(text1[i])
        else:
            result.append('??')
    # Add remaining elements from the longer text
    if len(text1) > len(text2):
        result.extend(['?' for _ in range(len(text2), len(text1))])
    elif len(text2) > len(text1):
        result.extend(['?' for _ in range(len(text1), len(text2))])
    return result

# Convert hexadecimal strings to decimal values
def hex_to_dec(hex_str):
    return int(hex_str, 16)

text1_hex = ['F3', '0C', '11', '68']
text2_hex = ['F3', '0F', 'D1', '68']

text1 = [hex_to_dec(hex_str) for hex_str in text1_hex]
text2 = [hex_to_dec(hex_str) for hex_str in text2_hex]

result = compare_and_print(text1, text2)
print(result)
```

and i was expecting the result to be printed like:

```
F3 0? ?1 68
```

but it printed out like [243, '??', '??', 104] and i dont want even brackets and it also converted things like F3 to 243 and again thats not what i want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

after testing some other "new" chat taps in AI chat bots finally got this :

```
def compare_texts(text1, text2, text3):
    result = []
    for t1, t2, t3 in zip(text1, text2, text3):
        if t1 == t2 == t3:
            result.append(t1)
        else:
            result.append('??')
    return ' '.join(result)

text1 = input("Enter the first text: ").split()
text2 = input("Enter the second text: ").split()
text3 = input("Enter the third text: ").split()

print(compare_texts(text1, text2, text3))
```

even tho it didnt do it for an exact single wildcard change and had to change the 2 characters with "??" (even if character 2 matches in all text) it was close enough for me

Comment: but if anyone else found a more accurate alternative way I'm open to suggestions